# Visual Studio - different sets of breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio (2015 and newer), is it possible to have multiple sets of breakpoins? I have several scenarios, I need to debug, but for each of them I would like to have different set of breakpoints. It is quite time-consuming to enable/disable them manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can export and import breakpoints from the breakpoints window and then import them as required.

[image: Visual Studio 15 breakpoints window]

Alternatively, if you don't mind modifying your code, you can use conditional breakpoints and set the condition in your code. E.g., set a boolean `testingScenario1 = true` and then set a breakpoint condition on the breakpoint to only break when `testingScenario1 == true`.

Or use `Debugger.Break()`. Something like:

```
#if DEBUG
    if (testingScenario1)
        Debugger.Break();
#endif
```