# Saving multiple sets of breakpoints as different profiles - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

Is there an inbuilt feature in Visual Studio 2017 to save multiple sets of breakpoints in different profiles which can be switched easily.

**UseCase:** In large projects, it is sometimes required to focus only on one set of *flow-1*, then switch back to another set of *flow-2* where each flow has its own set of breakpoints and you don't want to get *flow-1*'s breakpoints to hit.

> The MSDN link given in the SO answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454551/visual-studio-different-sets-of-breakpoints), is no longer
>   valid.
>
> And anything better than [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454551/visual-studio-different-sets-of-breakpoints) import/export solution?
>   This approach has one limitation - "*Breakpoint Import depends on the line number where you have set your breakpoint earlier. If your line number changed the breakpoint will set on the previous line number only, so you will get breakpoints on unexpected lines.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Visual Studio **Breakpoints** window you can label breakpoints for flow-1 or flow-2:

[image]

Then, to quickly enable or disable a group of breakpoints, you can **Search** for flow-1 or flow-2 and click the **Enable or disable all breakpoints matching the current search creteria** button.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your break point by using the option save as in break point windows

It will save as XML file. When and where ever your want, you can place this file. So that you can see the break point where ever you have used.

Reference link: [Import or Export breakpoints in visual studio](http://dailydotnettips.com/2012/12/11/import-and-export-breakpoints-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: This import/export workaround I am already aware of it as mentioned in my question. This approach has some limitation - 
"*Breakpoint Import depends on the line number where you have set your breakpoint earlier. If your line number changed, breakpoint will set on the previous line number only, so you will get breakpoints on unexpected lines.*"

Comment: @Koder101: you are a developer. Please take a short time to think about how you would figure out whether a breakpoint has to be moved or deleted with a code change, especially when that code change was not done by yourself in your instance of VS but by someone else, e.g. via github. You'll likely find out that it's impossible to guess which line should have the breakpoint afterwards. It's not implemented in VS and will not be.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Yes Thomas, your comment is really thoughtful in case of code change. However, I think in case of no code change, VS should have given an inbuilt feature for profiling breakpoints (*obviously with T&C*).

Comment: @Koder101, Breakpoints label provide the ability to group or filter breakpoints like Sergey's suggestion, is it helpful for you?