# MSVC: how to export / import all breakpoints?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, export, breakpoints

MSVC: how to export / import all breakpoints?

Reason of the question: preventing accidental "Delete All Breakpoints".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to myself.

You can export and import breakpoints from the breakpoints window and then import them as required. See details in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42455477/1778275.